# Lit-Element doesn't let me set property value in html

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I have a issue with a as specific element I'm working on. And for some reason this one doesn't let me specify any property values on the html tag.

If I specify defaults in the contructor, then the element works fine with those defaults, but I cannot override the defaults via declarative html.

This is the element:

```
class OstinatoFetchTriggers extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      /**
        * The query selector for the `ostinato-fetch` element to use when
        * making the request.
        */
      xhrSelector: { type: String },

      /**
      * Elements with the trigger selector will have their click event
      * intercepted and will make the request via ostinato-fetch
      */
      triggerSelector: { type: String },
    };
  }


  constructor() {
    super();
    this.xhrSelector = '#xhrContent';
    this.triggerSelector = '[xhr-link]';
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();

    // The output for console log below is null or whatever the default was in the contructor.
    console.log(this.triggerSelector);

    var triggerList = document.querySelectorAll(this.triggerSelector);
    triggerList.forEach((trigger) => {
      trigger.addEventListener('click', this._handleXhrClick.bind(this));
    });
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    var triggerList = document.querySelectorAll(this.triggerSelector);
    triggerList.forEach((trigger) => {
      trigger.removeEventListener('click', this._handleXhrClick.bind(this));
    });
  }

  _handleXhrClick(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.triggerRequest(ev.currentTarget.href);
  }

  triggerRequest(href) {
    document.querySelector(this.xhrSelector).fetch(href);
  }
}

customElements.define('ostinato-fetch-triggers', OstinatoFetchTriggers);
```

I try to use the element above like this: `<ostinato-fetch-triggers xhr-selector="#somethingElse"></ostinato-fetch-triggers>`.

What I expect is that the xhrTriggers property in the element should be `#somethingElse`, but this is not the case. It basically just uses the default from the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Since the lit-element didn't have the concept to map property name to attribute name by convert camel-case to dash-case like in Polymer 2. So if you declare `xhrSelector`, you must use:

```
<ostinato-fetch-triggers xhrSelector="#somethingElse"></ostinato-fetch-triggers>
```

---

Second: The `connectedCallback` is a native [lifecycle callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) not from `lit-element` which means there is no guarantee when it invoked the `lit-element` is already set the properties. You can use `firstUpdated(changedProperties)` or `update(changedProperties)` if you want to react each time of property changed.

See more about lit-element [lifecycle](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element#advanced-update-lifecycle).

---

Third: In `disconnectedCallback`, it seems you want to remove the listener but this will not work because every time you execute `bind` function it will return the new function which mean you try to remove the function that never be added before.

You should keep the listener in some variable

```
let listener = this._handleXhrClick.bind(this)
trigger.addEventListener('click', listener)
this.listeners.push({ trigger, listener })
```

then in `disconnectedCallback`

```
this.listeners.forEach(({ trigger, listener }) => {
  listener.removeEventListener('click', listener)
})
```